# Filter Table Triggers when using SMO DependencyWalker

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have a database with numerous tables that I use the SMO DependencyTree and DependencyWalker to order them by dependencies and then script them out.  However, there are two particular tables that have the following relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE Production_Events (
    Event_Id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Start_Time datetime NOT NULL,
    End_Time datetime null
    --... other columns
)

CREATE TABLE Production_Event_Data (
    Production_Event_Data_Id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Event_Id int NOT NULL, -- Foreign key to the above table
    Variable_Id int NOT NULL, -- Foreign key to another table
    Variable_Value varchar(25) NULL
    --... other columns
)
```

The Production_Event table has a FOR INSERT trigger which populates the Production_Event_Data table with values that come from various sources when a new row is inserted in Production_Event.

If there is no trigger present on the Production_Event table, the DependencyWalker will properly order these tables for scripting by detecting the Foreign Key relationship between them.  However, if the trigger is present, then DependencyWalker sees the trigger as a dependency and orders the tables incorrectly by putting the Production_Event_Data table before the Production_Events.  Ultimately this will end with a Foreign Key Constraint error if you try to execute the script.

Is there a way to configure DependencyWalker to only account for table dependencies and NOT trigger dependencies?